# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't recognise my screen resolution

Tags: resolution

This version of Ubuntu not working properly. This version does not recognize:the brand of my screen. I tried everything. I need my Ubuntu Acknowledge monitor and each time I restart the drivers do not delete my monitor?

ESPECIFICATIONS SYSTEM

- CPU:                      AMD Phenom (tm) II X4 965 Processor x4
- RAM:                      4GB
- VIDEO CARD GRAPHICS:      ATI HD7870-DC2-2GD5 ASUS
- SCREEN MODEL:             LG FLATRON W2243S

Command Output: `xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   848x480        60.0
   640x480        59.9
```

the problem is that people have a monkey with connection "VGA" and my video graphics card is "DVI" connection and I use a converter "VGA " to "DVI" to connect and why ubuntu does not recognize my monitor. = ( And I know, because I just tested the display having my brother , this screen is "DVI" the probe and works :(

Comment: How can anyone possibly help you?  You did not give any PC specs, nothing about the monitor.  Did the system ever run with Ubuntu previously?  We need much more to go on here...

Comment: Identify your hardware, your video card in particular.

Comment: CPU:                                                 AMD Phenom (tm) II X4 965 Processor x4
RAM:                                                4GB
VIDEO CARD GRAPHICS:        ATI HD7870-DC2-2GD5 ASUS
SCRENN MODEL:                       LG FLATRON W2243S

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/620351/edit) your question and add the output of `xrandr -q`

Comment: Command Output: xrandr -q Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384 DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) DVI-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm 1024x768 60.0* 800x600 60.3 56.2
848x480 60.0
640x480 59.9

Comment: Which graphics adapter driver does your system use? (The output of `sudo lshw -class display` would be one way to find out.)

Comment: You can manually set screen resolution in xorg.conf. But it is not quite simple. There are manuals in the net.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is fairly late, but I'm using an adapter too and had the exact same problem. Whenever I tried to force the resolution using

```
$ xrandr --newmode <insert cvt mode>
$ xrandr --addmode DVI-0 1920x1080_60.00
$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

This would throw me into "Out of Range". What I did was add `--rate 60` to the last command.

Answer (score 0):

Install proprietary AMD drivers.

System settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional drivers.

Comment: The problem is not the video graphics card , the problem is that ubuntu does not recognize the model of my screen, does not recognize its maximum resolution is 1920x1080 , I say this because sometimes when I turn the pc ubuntu recognizes the model of my screen and its resolution, but when I turn off the PC and turn again , ubuntu, returns to the same problem already and described .

Note : I tried this solution , and when I install private drivers , and reboot the PC, ubuntu gives an error , my screen stays black . and then I have to re- install the operating system again.

Comment: Graphics adapter drivers are responsible for recognising screen capabilities and resolutions (in accord with the graphics adapter of course), so this answer may help in your situation.

Comment: go back and repeat the problem is not the driver my video card , and I say this because in the past, for example, 3 days ago , ubuntu recognize the make and model of my screen when selected the Display Properties ubuntu was saying that it was a : gold star xxx , this means it is a LG FLATRON W2243S , and this allows me to have a resolution of 1920x1080, but when I turn off and turn on the pc , sometimes me in display properties , this monitor is unknown, and this will not let me change resolutions

Comment: This may be because of bad monitor cable, or bad contact. Especially if it happens randomly.

Comment: It can be, but when I'm in window 7 , this does not happen to me

Comment: the problem is that people have a monkey with connection "VGA" and my video graphics card is "DVI" connection and I use a converter "VGA " to "DVI" to connect and why ubuntu does not recognize my monitor. = ( And I know, because I just tested the display having my brother , this screen is "DVI" the probe and works  :(